# Divs dont have a gap between them in tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

So basically, I want to know how I can add a gap between these divs with grid in tailwind. For some reason this is not working.

```
 <section class="mt-6 grid gap-4 grid-cols-4 text-white">
        <div class="flex justify-center border border-white">Calculator</div>
        <div class="flex justify-center border border-white">Who's that pokemon?</div>
        <div class="border-white border">What's the weather like?</div>
        <div class="border-white border">To-Do-List</div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. I checked it in Playground

https://play.tailwindcss.com/a2kk7R7TmK

Answer (score 0):

`gap` className is works with `display:flex;` `display:grid;`

Your code should be:

```
<section class="flex mt-6 grid gap-4 grid-cols-4 text-white">
  // Your Code       
</section>
```

Comment: "gap className is only works with display:flex;" this is not true

Comment: i mean that flex works with flex and grid